# How to say "it's a question of" or "it's all about"?

Tags: classical-latin, example-request, idiom

How can I express something like the following sentences in Latin?

- Being a teacher is simple; it's a question of discipline.
- I don't care if I win or not; it's all about surviving.

I can offer some translations:

- Facile est magister esse; nullo opus est nisi disciplina.
- Mea non interest an vincam necne; de pervivendo agitur.

I believe these translations would be understood correctly, but I fear they might not be all that idiomatic to classical Latin.
**What would be a good idiomatic way to express things like this in classical Latin? Please provide a classical use example.**
I prefer Caesar or Cicero if there is room for choice.

Comment: I would definitely go with "agitur" and its forms: it's very similar to French "il s'agit" and Spanish "se trata de"

Comment: Living Latin folks seem to use *tractátur dé (aliquó)* (as in @brianpck's "se trata de"), but as I can't provide you with any classical examples I won't post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cicero uses *quaestio*, as in *quaestio est iurene occiderit...*, implying the meaning "problem (concerning)". Maybe the preposition *circa* could help, in the appropriate context; Greek has the perfect περὶ + gen.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: You have already been very helpful! This is an interesting answer. Can you give an example or two in Cicero's (or someone else's) work that uses this construction?

Comment: Well, for example, Quintilian VII, 3 et al. sees the similar construction _quaestio est an..._ But since Cicero is more involved in legal issues than other authors, _quaestio_ in his work has more to share with _controversia_ than simply "matter" as in "a matter of". The word itself could be generally translated as "disputed point", which is not quite what you asked for, but I bet you could turn it around to mean what you want it to mean :D Glad this helped you

Comment: @giobrach Do you know if *quaestio* here is mostly a judicial term? I know that *quaestio* is must more like English *investigation* than *question*

Comment: It has been used with either meaning of "question/matter/subject (of any debate)" and "legal dispute/trial/investigation", depending on the context, although the latter one is more frequent due to (a) an abundance of writings concerning trials and the law in general (by Cicero foremost) and (b) the fact that the word comes from _quaero_ "to seek" — at least these are my educated guesses. The first meaning is more frequently found in treatises about philosophy or oratory, also in Medieval Latin: cf. _Naturales Quaestiones_ by Seneca the Younger, and _Quaestio de aqua et terra_ by Dante, etc.

Comment: Your answer and comments have been very enlightening. I will accept your answer now. If someone comes along with an answer that more directly addresses my question, I might move my acceptance there.