# What is it about?

Tags: grammar-choice

I believe "liber de bellō est" would mean "the book is about/concerning war".  What question would elicet that as a response? I.e. how would I say "what is the book about/concerning?"? "De quid/quo est liber?" Or would I need to use māteria or rēs to say something like "what is the subject of the book?"

Gratias vobis ago
Paulus

Comment: *De quo* works for me. *De quid* is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural phrase to mean to "deal with"/"[a question of](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/678/how-to-say-its-a-question-of-or-its-all-about)" is ***de aliqua re agitur***. We can thus have *in hoc libero de arte belli agitur* (This book deals with the art of war). There are indeed several examples (non classical - for now did not find a classical one specifically about book/works) like: *LIBER SECUNDUS In quo agitur de Processu causarum Appellationum*. The question to elicit this would therefore be ***de quo [negotio] agitur in hoc libro?***.

I chose to first adhere to the common expression with the passive *agitur*; however, it might be more fitting to simply use the active *ago*. We have the phrase *agere de/cum aliqua re*, while extended in scope, can be used in our case. Hence we could have the question: ***cum/de qua [re] liber agit?***

There are more options, namely other verbs that can be used instead of the monstrous *ago*: One of them is the verb *tracto* which can be attached directly with *de*. Again, I have found many non-classical [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22liber%20tractat%22&ei=EFkxY76_IcOjkwWa0rtg&ved=0ahUKEwi-h5Pq-7H6AhXD0aQKHRrpDgwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22liber%20tractat%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QCDIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUIQHWIQHYOAIaAFwAHgAgAGZAYgBmQGSAQMwLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) specifically about *liber*.